# How to get web camera fps rate in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, c, video, opencv, webcam

So I need to get web camera fps rate in OpenCV. Which function can do such thing for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int cvGetCaptureProperty( CvCapture* capture, int property_id);
```

with `property_id = CV_CAP_PROP_FPS`

Comment: this does not work for me.  in opencv/python given that cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0), print "frame rate = ", cap.get(5)   gives me a fps of zero.   note that fps is constant 5 for cv_cap_prop.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for live webcam capture, you can set an arbitrary fps and read back that same fps, which has nothing to do with the real fps from webcam. Is it a bug?

For example:

```
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,500);
```

and later

```
double rates = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
printf("%f\n",rates);
```

will give you 500.

But if I timed it using [web cam fps link](http://sublimated.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/benchmarking-frames-per-second-when-using-opencvs-cvcapturefromcam/), it's around the normal 30fps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) did not work.

So, I found this code in this link:

https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-find-frame-rate-or-frames-per-second-fps-in-opencv-python-cpp/

```
import cv2
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

    # Find OpenCV version
    (major_ver, _, _) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

    # With webcam get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) does not work.
    # Let's see for ourselves.

    if int(major_ver) < 3:
        fps = video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print "Frames per second using video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS): {0}".format(fps)
    else:
        fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print "Frames per second using video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) : {0}".format(fps)

    # Number of frames to capture
    num_frames = 120

    print "Capturing {0} frames".format(num_frames)

    # Start time
    start = time.time()

    # Grab a few frames
    for i in xrange(0, num_frames):
        ret, frame = video.read()

    # End time
    end = time.time()

    # Time elapsed
    seconds = end - start
    print "Time taken : {0} seconds".format(seconds)

    # Calculate frames per second
    fps = num_frames / seconds
    print "Estimated frames per second : {0}".format(fps);

    # Release video
    video.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

*OpenCV 2 solution:

```
C++: double VideoCapture::get(int propId)
```

E.g.

```
VideoCapture myvid("video.mpg");
int fps=myvid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```